# Почему у меня другой шрифт на IPhone в Safari?

Tags: html, css, браузер

Ссылка на сайт: http://tort-muffin.by/

Не корректно отображаются шрифты на айфонах. Почему так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает шрифт Montserrat от Google. Заменил на Open Sans - заработало нормально. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Баг iOS 14 https://stackoverflow.com/q/64256826/1016033